# AppleScript in Org-Mode source code blocks?

Tags: org-mode

Does anyone know how to setup org-mode so that you can write/process applescript from within org source code blocks? I.e.,

```
#+BEGIN_SRC applescript

tell application "Emacs"
    [do something amazing]
end tell

#+END_SRC
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's super rough, but I managed to get a very, very basic integration working last night. Hope it is useful: https://github.com/stig/ob-applescript.el -- that should at least give you something to work with.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Stig — great job!!!

Comment: You're welcome. If [this PR is merged](https://github.com/melpa/melpa/pull/4242) you should be able to install this module from Melpa. I also updated the module to support the `apples-mode` major mode, and table output.

Comment: You can now install this using package.el from MELPA.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if Org Babel supports AppleScript, but it supports bash. You can run applescript from Bash using `osascript` and a bash `heredoc`:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh
  osascript <<'END'
  display dialog "Hello, World"
  END
#+END_SRC
```

SE doesn't allow proper formatting. The `END` statement should be all the way to the left, with no spaces before it.

Comment: Emacs supports `do-applescript` (an alias for `ns-do-applescript`) from `ns-win.el`, so it could also be an `elisp` code block that calls said function.

Comment: Thanks @mankoff! Good tip. I was hoping to find a way to support AppleScript directly though, so I could apply font-locking...

Answer (score 1):

Would a bit of indirection be OK? You can use `noweb` to have an applescript
block inserted into a shell block for execution…

```
#+name: hello-apples
#+BEGIN_SRC apples
display dialog "Hello, World"
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC sh :noweb yes :exports both
osascript -e '<<hello-apples>>'
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: button returned:OK
```

I'm using `apples-mode` because it appears to have better font-locking than `applescript-mode` but you can use either.

Comment: That's a pretty neat hack. It looks like org-babel has built-in support for new languages though. Here is the link: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages.html. They also provide a template for defining new languages: http://orgmode.org/w/worg.git/blob/HEAD:/org-contrib/babel/ob-template.el. I would love to find a solution that makes use of this...

Comment: Seems useful. I might take a stab at that...

Comment: Super rough, but works for very simple cases: https://github.com/stig/ob-applescript.el